# I keep getting CS7036 on line 22 and 35

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I know that this is pretty simple for others but, I don't know why I keep Getting the error saying

> there is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter `width` of `Rect.Rect(float, float, float, float)`

when compiling even though I just need the position and the size so that I can render a white line. sorry, I'm still new to coding C#

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class Render
{
    public static GUIStyle StringStyle { get; set; } = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.label);

    public static Color Color
    {
        get { return GUI.color; }
        set { GUI.color = value; }
    }

    public static void DrawBox(Vector2 position, Vector2 size, Color color, bool centered = true)
    {
        Color = color;
        DrawBox(position, size, centered);
    }
    public static void DrawBox(Vector2 position, Vector2 size, bool centered = true)
    {
        var upperLeft = centered ? position - size / 2f : position;
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(position, size), Texture2D.whiteTexture, ScaleMode.StretchToFill);
    }

    public static void DrawString(Vector2 position, string label, Color color, bool centered = true)
    {
        Color = color;
        DrawString(position, label, centered);
    }
    public static void DrawString(Vector2 position, string label, bool centered = true)
    {
        var content = new GUIContent(label);
        var size = StringStyle.CalcSize(content);
        var upperLeft = centered ? position - size / 2f : position;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(upperLeft, size), content);
    }

    public static Texture2D lineTex;
    public static void DrawLine(Vector2 pointA, Vector2 pointB, Color color, float width)
    {
        Matrix4x4 matrix = GUI.matrix;
        if (!lineTex)
            lineTex = new Texture2D(1, 1);

        Color color2 = GUI.color;
        GUI.color = color;
        float num = Vector3.Angle(pointB - pointA, Vector2.right);

        if (pointA.y > pointB.y)
            num = -num;

        GUIUtility.ScaleAroundPivot(new Vector2((pointB - pointA).magnitude, width), new Vector2(pointA.x, pointA.y + 0.5f));
        GUIUtility.RotateAroundPivot(num, pointA);
        GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(pointA.x, pointA.y, 1f, 1f), lineTex);
        GUI.matrix = matrix;
        GUI.color = color2;
    }

    public static void DrawBox(float x, float y, float w, float h, Color color, float thickness)
    {
        DrawLine(new Vector2(x, y), new Vector2(x + w, y), color, thickness);
        DrawLine(new Vector2(x, y), new Vector2(x, y + h), color, thickness);
        DrawLine(new Vector2(x + w, y), new Vector2(x + w, y + h), color, thickness);
        DrawLine(new Vector2(x, y + h), new Vector2(x + w, y + h), color, thickness);
    }

    public static void DrawBoxOutline(Vector2 Point, float width, float height, Color color, float thickness)
    {
        DrawLine(Point, new Vector2(Point.x + width, Point.y), color, thickness);
        DrawLine(Point, new Vector2(Point.x, Point.y + height), color, thickness);
        DrawLine(new Vector2(Point.x + width, Point.y + height), new Vector2(Point.x + width, Point.y), color, thickness);
        DrawLine(new Vector2(Point.x + width, Point.y + height), new Vector2(Point.x, Point.y + height), color, thickness);
    }
}
```

I tried doing this

```
public static void DrawString(Vector2 position, string label, bool centered = true)
{
    var content = new GUIContent(label);
    var size = StringStyle.CalcSize(content);
    var upperLeft = centered ? position - size / 2f : position;
    GUI.Label(new Rect(upperLeft.x, upperLeft.y, size.x, size.y), content);
}
```

and then this

```
public static void DrawBox(Vector2 position, Vector2 size, bool centered = true)
{
var upperLeft = centered ? position - size / 2f : position;
float width = size.x; // Assuming size is a Vector2
float height = size.y; // Assuming size is a Vector2
GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(position.x, position.y, width, height), Texture2D.whiteTexture, ScaleMode.StretchToFill);
}
```

it compiled, but whenever i call it, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `DrawBox` you do this:
`GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(position, size), Texture2D.whiteTexture, ScaleMode.StretchToFill);`

[The constructor of `Rect` needs 4 floats](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rect-ctor.html)

So you want to do something like this instead:

`GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(position.x, position.y, size.x,size.y), Texture2D.whiteTexture, ScaleMode.StretchToFill);`

Comment: won't it affect anything when i try doing `Render.DrawLine(this.robot.transform.position, this.metalObject.transform.position, Color.white, 1);` from point A to point B?

Comment: btw, i managed to compile it. using the `this.robot.transform.position` might be wrong on my part since the transform position uses vector3 because its a top-down 3d game. anyway, thanks for the help Raildex!